# Error: 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, html, web

So i'm having this trouble. Errors on lines 3,4,5. This is how i define object properties:

```
class Article {
//line 3
public $id; // line 4
public $pubDate; // line 5
public $title;
public $content;
```

And here is my method that gives an error:

```
  public static function getById( $id ) {
  $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
  $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pubDate) AS pubDate FROM material WHERE id = :id";
  $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
  $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
  $st->execute();
  $row = $st->fetch();
  $conn = null;
  if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );
}
```

I've tried to disable error by using:

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

But it's only masks the problem, publication still doe's not appear on page.
Thank you.

This is function constructor:

```
public function __construct($data = array()) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['pubDate'] ) ) $this->pubDate = $data['pubDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = $data['title'];
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
}
```

And function that calls getById method:

```
function viewArticle() {
if ( !isset( $_GET["articleId"] ) || !$_GET["articleId"] ) {
    homepage();
    return;
}

$results = array();
$results['article'] = Article::getById( (int) $_GET["articleId"] );
$results['pageTitle'] = $results['article']->title;
require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/viewArticle.php" );
```

}

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Btw, you should never just try and suppress errors.

Comment: There's not 34 lines in the above. Please mark the lines with a comment.

Comment: Sorry. It's been corrected.

Comment: there is no code in your question that tries to get a property of an object ... also no have no constructor for your article class so check out what new Article($row) really produces or what $row contains

Comment: `conn` and `sql` should be `$conn` and `$sql`. Close this please.

Comment: Hiding the error messages does not magically make some wrong code works. You have to make the code work, not pretend it works and hide the errors. As a developer, the error messages are your friend, they frankly tell you why the code doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Seems odd that it would tell you that there are errors on lines 3, 4 and 5. It would usually hit one and throw an error, not collect data from all errors and show them to you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been found. Problem was - my stupidity.
Best regards for all who guided me and responded to my plea for help.